Verb Above Association in USE CASE Diagram
I've started drawing use case diagrams and I have a quick question.
Can we place a verb or any action above the association (line) connecting the actor to the use case (or feature in an oval)?
For example, if there is a login use case to access further application features, can we write something like "Must (actor must log in) to access further features"?
Please guide me, and let me know if this is completely wrong, or if we should never write a verb above the association. If possible, could you provide a link to an explanation or resource on this topic?
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/TF0hmGJj.jpg
